# UILabel smooth animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel

I'm looking for a way to make my interface look smoother. Is there a way to add UILabel change animation as shown below? I've looked through all of the libraries lists and found nothing similar.

[image: animation]

Comment: Try https://github.com/lexrus/LTMorphingLabel

Comment: Your question is not fit for SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions. Also, be glad that @Sweeper gave you a good solution.

Comment: try this link https://github.com/overboming/ZCAnimatedLabel, hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

This is best solution for you issue, this project has same animation that you want :

https://github.com/tomknig/TOMSMorphingLabel

What you need to do is :

- Copy 4 files from "Classes" folders, paste in to your project
- take any UILabel in storyboard, and set its class as "TOMSMorphingLabel"
- set text (like your example) "0" initially from storyboard
- in viewDidLoad of you controller set your new text - "05"

  ```
  [_textLabel setText:@"05"];
  ```

Comment: It's absolutely what I need, but it's for Objective-C, if I'm right

Comment: then you can convert that code to swift.. or you can use bridge to get objective-c support